# How can I find out which JavaScript engines/platforms support which features of ES6 Unicode regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, ecmascript-6, standards

I often work with many human languages and writing systems and I try to use the most modern features of JavaScript that I can.

I often find I would like to use modern Unicode regular expression such as Unicode Property Escapes:

```
/\p{L}/
```

It seems that though many JS platforms are including more and more ES6 features, these Unicode regex features are lagging behind.

How can I found out which engines/platforms support which of these features? By "platform" I include things like transpilers.

I'm aware of the excellent [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) for a great workaround, but how can I monitor/track this support getting included natively in the various JS implementations?

I suppose something like [Can I use](http://caniuse.com) might be what I'm looking for. But maybe something that tracks ES6 support, that tracks Unicode support, or that tracks regular expression support might also exist? Or maybe there are various bug reports and feature requests I can subscribe to?

Comment: For `\p{L}`, none of them support that, so your answer is "you can't". The RegExp docs on MDN cover the supported syntax, have you looked at that? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp The syntax you're asking about is a proposal: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-property-escapes

Comment: Babel does support it but seems to require you to turn it on specifically. [V8 apparently supports it as of a few days or weeks ago but behind a setting for now.](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/07/upcoming-regexp-features#unicode_property_escapes) But yeah that's why I want a way to check the progress rather than just how it is in September 2017.

Comment: Are you asking how to do feature detection on regexes, or are you looking for a resource that has a support table? The latter question would be off-topic on SO.

Comment: @Bergi: I'm looking for any way to deal with this real issue I continually face as a programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[compat-table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/#test-RegExp_Unicode_Property_Escapes) for RegExp_Unicode_Property_Escapes feature

Some related features

- [u_flag](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-RegExp_y_and_u_flags)
- [u_flag,_case_folding](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-RegExp_u_flag,_case_folding)
- [s_flag](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/#test-s_(dotAll)_flag_for_regular_expressions)  .. ([us combo](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es-regexp-proposals#dotAll) ex)

Comment: Awesome! I was looking at kangax yesterday but was too dumb to figure it out. But as Unicode property escapes was just one example, can I find on kangax all the new Unicode regex features? The items adjacent to it in the table are not things I've come up against. (Possibly I just had different property escape problems before and didn't think of them as "the same thing" though...)

Comment: @hippietrail handpicking

Answer (score 1):

In lieu of a full centralized resource, here's the issue/feature trackers I've been able to locate so far at least for Unicode property escapes in regular expressions:

- Mozilla/Firefox - [Bug 1361876 - Implement RegExp Unicode Property Escapes](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1361876)
- Microsoft/ChakraCore - [[Feature] Implement RegExp Unicode property escapes #2969](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/issues/2969)
- WebKit - [Bug 172069 - Implement RegExp Unicode property escapes](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=172069)
- Google V8 - [Issue 4743 - Implement unicode regexp property class](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4743&desc=2)